# "Make a Link" Nautilus extension functionality now missing in 21.04?

Tags: files, 21.04, nautilus-extensions

I right-clicked on a file expecting to find the "Make a Link" choice, but it's now missing!

Anybody know where it went?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in versions of nautilus prior to 40.2 that comes with Ubuntu 21.10, this is an optional right-click menu item, turned off by default in Ubuntu. Enable it from the Preferences (≡ menu, Preferences).

In Nautilus 3.36, the setting "Show action to create symbolic links" is on the "Behavior" tab under "Link creation":

[image]

In Nautilus 40, the option "Create link" appears under the section "Optional Context Menu Action":

[image: Nautilus Preferences]

Comment: "previous" sounds vague. Which exactly versions? Who decided that it is optonal? For example Caja do not hide this option for years.

Comment: @N0rbert indicated version number (to make answer more future proof without context). "Optional" because it can be turned on/turned off in the preferences. In stock Gnome and in Ubuntu, it always has been off by default. Many thanks for adding the screenshot!

Comment: In Ubuntu 21.04, my Nautilus (3.38.2-stable) preferences don't look anything like this. Are you using 21.10, or something other than Ubuntu, perhaps?

Comment: Hi, didn' t realize it was you asking the question. And I  mislooked the version - this is a picture of 21.10. Still, the option should be there in previous versions as well, on I think even the first tab of the preferences dialog. - I will check on a 20.04.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot check the actual 21.04 version, but I added a screenshot for 20.04. I would be surprised if that would have changed in 21.04, so please let me know if the option is not there for you. If needed, I can add a  dconf setting to set it anyway.

Comment: You're absolutely correct! There's that pref! I wonder how it got turned off? Thanks!